# Template Variable Causing Template Parse Error: There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "#start_date"

Tags: angular, pug, angular-material2, webpack-2

Attempting to build a [Material Design datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) following their docs.

Note: the **end goal** is to bind the datepicker input to a component variable, however I can't get past this most basic part.

I'm sure I'm doing something dumb!

Error in console:

> `Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>   There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "#start_date" ("Change)="updateFilters()" placeholder="Search"/><input mat-datepicker="start_date"/><mat-datepicker [ERROR ->]#start_date="#start_date"></mat-datepicker><select name="type" [(ngModel)]="filters.fields.type" (ngM"): ng:///AppModule/AccountingComponent.html@0:574`

Pug file:

```
.filters
  input(mat-datepicker="start_date")
  mat-datepicker(#start_date)
```

Transpiled HTML:

```
<div class="filters">
    <input mat-datepicker="start_date" />
    <mat-datepicker #start_date="#start_date"></mat-datepicker>
</div>
```

Clearly Angular doesn't like the `#start_date` attribute on the input, but my understanding of [template reference variables](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars) is weak, and I've been unable to find a resource that helps sort out what I'm doing wrong.

What needs to change to make this work properly?

**NOTE** - I'm using Webpack 3, with [pug-html-loader](https://github.com/willyelm/pug-html-loader) to transpile pug => html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are to trying insert a value within a property of mat-datepicker where you should insert the type of the variable. The template variable is #start_date="HTMLDomElement"

```
<mat-datepicker #start_date="string"></mat-datepicker>
```

The final should be

```
 <mat-datepicker #startDate></mat-datepicker>
```

Component

```
@ViewChild('startDate') startDate : HTMLDOMElement(i.e);
```

Comment: Interesting.  I had considered that, but in this project, webpack is transpiling the pug... so now my problem is handling _that_ issue.  Thank you - I'll report back once I've sorted that bit out.

Answer (score 1):

[@Antonio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50296282/870729) is correct.

As I was using Webpack 3, and transpiling pug with [pug-html-loader](https://github.com/willyelm/pug-html-loader), I had to additionally sort out how to make it transpile as desired.

Ultimately, I needed to add the [doctype option](https://pugjs.org/language/doctype.html#doctype-option) to the pug transpilier (`doctype: 'html'` causes it to [add an attribute without the value](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/370)).

In order to do this, I needed to modify the Webpack config to pass the argument properly:

Old configuration of webpack.conf.js:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      // ... other rules omitted for brevity...
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        loaders: ['raw-loader', 'pug-html-loader'],
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [...]
}
```

Changed to NEW configuration of webpack.conf.js:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      // ... other rules omitted for brevity...
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        // NOTE: 'loaders' is deprecated in favor of 'use'
        use: [
          'raw-loader',
          {
            loader: 'pug-html-loader',
            options: {
              doctype: 'html'
            }
          }]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [...]
}
```